# Laravel: How can a queued job move itself to failed_jobs on fail?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a queueable Job that creates a new user...

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

...

class CreateNewUser implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /** @var array */
    public $newUserData;

    public function __construct($newUserData)
    {
        $this->newUserData = $newUserData;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $email = $this->newUserData['email'];
        if (User::whereEmail($email)->count()) {
            // TODO: Make this job fail immediately
            throw new UserWithEmailExistsException('User with email ' . $email . ' already exists');
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

It's a queued job because we batch process CSVs to load in many users at a time, each one requiring an entry in 2 tables plus multiple entries in roles and permissions tables. Too slow to do synchronously.

I have a check at the start of the `handle()` method to see if a user with the same email address has not already been created *(because potentially several jobs could be queued to create users with the same email)* and it throws a custom Exception if it does.

If that check fails, I don't ever want the queue worker to attempt this job again because I know it will continue to fail indefinitely, it's a waste of time to re-attempt even once more. **How can I manually force this job to fail once and for all and move over to the failed jobs table?**

P.S. I have found the SO answer about the `fail()` helper and the `$this->markAsFailed()` method but these still do not immediately move the job from jobs to failed_jobs.

Comment: Is there a reason you require the job to specifically fail if a user with a specific email already exists? Would it not be sufficient to mark the job as complete if the user exists instead, as technically the job is complete as you're adding a user whom has already been added..

Comment: Good point. You raise an interesting discussion around how to interpret "Failed". The code did not fail, the task did. It's possible that an error in the CSV data caused 2 different users to have the same email address. A copy-and-paste error by administrators at registration. I want that to be reported. Now I think about it I guess the job should be called "AttemptToInsertNewUser()" and possible successful outcomes are A) Create the user or B) Report the duplication on some reporting panel.

Comment: Yep, I think that seems more suitable. Logging of the duplication errors, but, continuing nevertheless seem's to be the correct logic. Hope you get around your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I've completely rewritten my answer for you. I was in a rush last night and thought I had a quick solution to your problem, sorry for the misinformation.

You could do something like the code below, this won't put the job into the failed jobs table but it will prevent the re-attempts from happening. I hope that helps.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class TestJob extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        if ($this->attempts() > 0) {
            // Will not reattempt this job.
            return;
        }

        throw new \Exception('Job will fail.');
    }
}
```

Comment: The task does do more than just check for duplicates so later code could fail for other reasons that would mean I would want it to retry.

Comment: @MartinJoiner if you don't want to retry it then you can simply set `$tries = 0;` therefore it would stop when an exception is hit. Hope that helps.

Comment: No it won't. The number of tries is set on the serialized version of the class which is saved in database. Changing this on the fly will not update the serialized version of the class. Please test your suggestions before posting them on stackoverflow.